# Python is restarting itself or crashing, presumably due to recursion depth

Tags: python, recursion

I'm working on  a program for Project Euler - Problem 15 - in which we need to find all of the paths through a 20 x 20 grid. I came up with a recursive method to solve it, but as of right now, the recursion goes very deep.

```
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000000)

def start():
    right = 0
    down = 0
    global acc
    acc = 0
    movel(right, down)
    moved(right, down)

def movel(right, down):
    right += 1
    if right == 20 and down == 20:
        acc += 1
    elif right == 20:
        moved(right, down)
    else:
        movel(right, down)
        moved(right, down)

def moved(right, down):
    down += 1
    if right == 20 and down == 20:
        acc += 1
    elif down == 20:
        movel(right, down)
    else:
        movel(right, down)
        moved(right, down)

start()

print(acc)
```

I set the recursion limit incredibly high, because I didn't want to exceed the max recursion limit.

When I run the program, it runs for a few seconds. Then, if I'm running it as an exe, it crashes - if I'm running it in the shell, it restarts the shell. What's causing this error in the code? I'm unsure if it's the maximum recursion depth being exceeded or some other issue.

(For any future reader, there's a detailed explanation in the comments, but more generally, a recursive function eventually needs to return something, and mine did not.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_termination - recursive functions need to include conditions according to which they stop recursing and start returning values, or else they will recurse infinitely

Comment: @danyamachine The intent of the program is to stop the chain of recursion when both variables are equal to twenty. Did I mess up and make a logic error there that I can't see?

Comment: If you have a problem with a recursive algorithm, your first step should not be to increase the recursion depth.. it should be to add print statements at the beginning of each recursive function to make sure you are trending toward a base case (or better yet - step through with a debugger).  Add `print("movel", right, down)` and `print("moved", right, down)` to the start of your functions.

Comment: One of my first computer science lectures just came back to my mind: "Don't write recursive code if it can be done without recursion. It can always be done without.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, there is a logical error in your recursion.

*Note*: A large part of the fun in solving Project Euler sums is to debug them yourself. I am posting the logical error in your code below, once you read it, you will lose the opportunity to have that *aha* moment, at least for this program.

1. `start()` calls `movel` with (0, 0)
2. `movel` increments right by 1, and calls itself. This is because:

   ```
   if right == 20 and down == 20:
       acc += 1
   elif right == 20:
       moved(right, down)
   ```

   is not true, and so it goes to the else part, which calls `movel()`
3. After 20 recursive calls, `right` is now 20. `down` is still 0.
4. `moved` is called for the first time, with arguments (20, 0)
5. `moved` increments `down` by 1, and `down` is now 1. Again, the first two checks fail in `moved`:

   ```
   if right == 20 and down == 20:
       acc += 1
   elif down == 20:
       movel(right, down)
   ```
6. **So now `moved` calls `movel` with arguments (20, 1). `movel` immediately increments `right`, and will from this point on get stuck in an infinite loop, since `right` will never equal 20.**

Cheers :)

Comment: Also when one value reaches `20` it will still recurse into the other function which calls after some time the first function again, increasing the value to `21`.